# PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not find xref table at specified location

Tags: python, django, pypdf

I have one problem after creating Django migration with the addition of validation of the file field.
my model is:

```
class TextItemSourceFile(models.Model):
    FILE_TYPE = 'text_source'
    BASE_DIR = 'text_source'

    EXT_WHITELIST = ('.doc', '.docx', '.odt', '.pdf', '.rtf', '.djvu', '.djv')
    MIME_WHITELIST = (
        'application/CDFV2-unknown',
        # for doc and docx files
        'application/msword',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
        # for odt files
        'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
        # for pdf files
        'application/pdf',
        'application/x-pdf',
        # for rtf files
        'text/rtf',
        'application/rtf',
        # for djvu files
        'image/vnd.djvu',
        'image/x-djvu'
    )

    MAX_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024

    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        verbose_name="UUID",
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        verbose_name="author",
        to='auth.User'
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date created",
        auto_now_add=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="original file name",
        max_length=200,
        null=False, blank=False
    )
    file = models.FileField(
        verbose_name="text file",
        upload_to=get_file_path, max_length=200,
        storage=OverwriteStorage(),
        null=False, blank=False,
        validators=[
            FileValidator(
                extension_whitelist=EXT_WHITELIST,
                mime_whitelist=MIME_WHITELIST,
                max_size=MAX_SIZE
            )
        ]
    )
    cover = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name="cover image",
        to=TextItemCoverFile,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    is_used = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="is used",
        default=False
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        prev = TextItemSourceFile.objects.filter(uuid=self.uuid).first()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if attr_changed(self, prev, 'file'):
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)[1].lower()
            if file_extension == '.pdf':
                cover = TextItemCoverFile(
                    author=self.author,
                    is_used=True
                )
                cover.file.save('cover.jpg', make_pdf_preview(self.file.name))
                cover.save()
                self.cover = cover
                self.save(force_update=True)
            else:
                self.cover = None
                self.save(force_update=True)
My validator is:

@deconstructible
class FileValidator(object):

    def __init__(self, extension_whitelist=None, mime_whitelist=None, max_size=None):
        self.extension_whitelist = extension_whitelist
        self.mime_whitelist = mime_whitelist
        self.max_size = max_size

    def __call__(self, value):
        if self.extension_whitelist is not None:
            self.validate_extension(value)

        if self.mime_whitelist is not None:
            self.validate_mime(value)

        if self.max_size is not None:
            self.validate_size(value)

    def validate_extension(self, file_obj):
        extension = os.path.splitext(file_obj.name)[1]
        if extension not in self.extension_whitelist:
            raise ValidationError(ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_FILE_FOUND)

    def validate_mime(self, file_obj):
        mime_type = magic.from_buffer(file_obj.read(2048), mime=True).decode('ascii')
        if mime_type not in self.mime_whitelist:
            raise ValidationError(ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_MIME)

    def validate_size(self, file_obj):
        if file_obj.size > int(self.max_size):
            raise ValidationError(ERROR_FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED)

/home/env/project/apps/abstract/utils.py
def make_pdf_preview(pdf_file_name):
    """

    :param pdf_file_name: of the PDF file that should be converted
    :return: content file with 1-st page converted to PNG
    """
    file_extension = os.path.splitext(pdf_file_name)[1].lower()
    assert file_extension == '.pdf'

    with storage.open(pdf_file_name, 'rb') as pdf_file:
        reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        writer = PdfFileWriter()
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        writer.write(stream)
        stream.seek(0)

        with wand_image(file=stream, resolution=200) as img:
            img.format = 'PNG'
            img.compression_quality = 99
            result_pic = io.BytesIO()
            img.save(file=result_pic)
            result_pic.seek(0)
            return ContentFile(result_pic.getvalue())

class TextFileAPITest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = APIClient()
        self.user, self.userp = create_user_with_profile('user')

    def test_text_file_upload(self):
        self.c.login(username=self.user.username, password='111')

        response = self.c.post(
            '/en/api/files/text_file/',
            data={
                'file': get_temporary_pdf()
            },
            format='multipart'
        )
```

#

```
def get_temporary_pdf(file_path=None):
    file_path = file_path or os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'test/test.pdf')
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as test_pdf:
        pdf_file = SimpleUploadedFile(file_path.split('/')[-1], test_pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')
        pdf_file.seek(0)
        return pdf_file
```

Before I added a validator to the model I had

```
PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]

After migrations, I run the test

Traceback (most recent call last):
.............................................................................
line 448, in save
    cover.file.save('cover.jpg', make_pdf_preview(self.file.name))
  File "/home/env/project/apps/abstract/utils.py", line 506, in make_pdf_preview
    reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
  File "/home/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "/home/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1901, in read
    raise utils.PdfReadError("Could not find xref table at specified location")
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not find xref table at specified location

That is, in the utility in the line 
reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
the exception is generated
```

I tried to change the test file as described here:
[PdfFileReader: PdfReadError: Could not find xref table at specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104818/pdffilereader-pdfreaderror-could-not-find-xref-table-at-specified-location)
But, this did not help me....
More varinats for this exception I have not seen on the Internet.
I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am struggling with the same. Please advise.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. I understand that it's frustrating, but there simply aren't any other good answers: (1) Fix the broken PDF document (2) Work on PyPDF2 to make it deal better with broken PDF documents. (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2 and I'm more than happy about robustness contributions - also about people creating issues including the PDFs that caused the issue)